# Are there any dangers in using Metro in Java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, java-metro-framework

Our java application needs to connect to outer web service which is running under windows, so we fetched WSDL, everything went fine... until we came to part in which we need to incorporate SSL communication for authentication purposes.

During the SSL handshake negotiation failed, so we end up with the problem, solution to which is in using Metro 2.0 libraries.

we put metro libraries which can handle microsoft specifics and so we succeeded to fetch data from that service, but there is one thing I am affraid of, and cannot test it:

Metro libraries are overriding javax.xml package, so application is not using  anymore Java's libraries, and since we are dependent to these classes, are there any critical changes in new classes which will change behaviour of system in a way that system will not work as expected?

Is there anyone experienced problems with changed behaviour due to relying to these libraries?

I need now to put system in work and worst possible scenario is: everything will function normally for days until system starts to show different behaviour, or we won't be able to notice changes on time..

Comment: What Metro distribution are you using? Exactly which jars have you added?

Comment: Metro 2.0 which you get in NetBeans 7.1

Answer (score 1):

'Metro libraries are overriding javax.xml package': I presume you mean XML parser (xerces).

Even if it's true (it's been a while since I used Metro last time) your logic seems to imply that the bugs most likely be in XML parser Metro is using and not in the one shipped with JDK which is not necessary the case. JDK is usually lagging in version of XML parser so most likely Metro is using a newer version (need to be checked) and at least it would be under your control, as a dependency - you could always test your app with a newer version of Metro before deploying to production as opposed to JDK which might just change with system upgrade or from system to system etc.

Comment: good point for using web services, what about parsing XML files, which I use also... this looks to me like importing new problems out of nowhere...